# translate while ( x < SomeTreshold ) in haskell

Tags: haskell

It occurs a lot when implementing algorithms that you check in every iteration of a while loop if a certain variable is smaller than a certain treshold.

In imperative languages it would look like :

```
 while ( x < TRESHOLD ) {
      x = usefullStuff();
 }
```

Where of course usefullStuff is affecting x somehow...

How do you translate this construct into haskell exploiting the functional programming paradigm?

Comment: Do you mean for `usefullStuff` to be a side-effecting function (i.e. an IO action in Haskell), or do you mean its value to depend on `x`?

Comment: `iterate usefullStuff x !! THESHOLD`

Comment: @is7s That applies the function `THRESHOLD` times. That's not what his `while` loop does. It also assumes the function takes `x` as its argument (which may or may not be the intention).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though I don't know what your program does, I have a feeling that you'll want to structure your logic a little differently. Have a look at section 4 of the paper [Why Functional Programming Mattes](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/whyfp90.pdf) - for some ideas. It deals with a similar situation involving finding the roots of an equation using Newton's method. There the responsibilities are partitioned so that the loop logic is decoupled from the generation of successive approximations.

If `usefulStuff` is a monad - i.e. a function with side effects, you'll have to use something like this:

```
whileLoop x
  | x < THRESHOLD = return x
  | otherwise     = do x <- usefulStuff
                       whileLoop x
```

Answer (score 5):

from Control.Monad.Loops:

```
iterateWhile :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> m a -> m a
iterateWhile p x = do
    y <- x
    if p y
      then iterateWhile p x
      else return y
```

Then, assuming usefullStuff has side effects:

```
iterateWhile (< threshold) usefullStuff
```

Answer (score 3):

Going by the description

> It occurs a lot when implementing algorithms that you check in every iteration of a while loop if a certain variable is smaller than a certain treshold.

I'd expect that you don't really mean an argument-less `usefullStuff` returning the new value of the control value `x`, but a transformation taking `x` as a parameter.

The direct translation of that is

```
until (>= threshold) usefullStuff x
```

Usually, though, there is more state than just the loop control, so one would have something like

```
until ((>= threshold) . getX) usefullStuff (someDataContaining x)
```

where `usefullStuff :: RecordContainingX -> RecordContainingX`.

If on the other hand `usefullStuff` is really meant to take no argument, if it's pure, it will always yield the same result, so you'd either never enter or never leave the loop. That's not too useful. So let's assume `usefullStuff` is an `IO`-action producing a value. Then

```
while :: Ord a -> (a -> Bool) -> a -> IO a -> IO a
while test value action
    | test value = do
               newValue <- action
               while test newValue action
    | otherwise  = return value
```

would capture the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

First: In an imperative language, you usually write a `while` loop who's body updates `x`. In Haskell, this cannot happen. Hence, we need to structure our algorithm a little differently.

What you'll typically do is turn the loop body into a *function* that takes `x` as an argument, and returns the new `x` value as its result. You can then use the `until` function from the Prelude to apply the function over and over until some condition is met. Alternatively, you can use `iterate` to generate an *infinite list* of all results, and then use `takeWhile` or some similar function to scan that list looking for the item of interest.

Now, what happens if your loop body actually updates *several* variables? Well, in that case, you can pack all those variables into a single data structure, and then the above procedure applies. It goes without saying that if you have *a lot* of these variables, this is probably going to get quite complicated. Try to avoid big, complex loops. (In any language, not just Haskell.)

You use the word "algorithm", which leads me to suspect that you're talking about things such as Dijkstra's shunting algorithm, or the Barnes-Hut n-body simulation algorithm, or some other "pure" algorithm. If, on the other hand, your loop body needs to perform updates over extremely large data structures, or needs to perform actual I/O operations (e.g., the main loop of a network server), then we need to run in a monad. This usually means that in-place updates *are* possible, and you can follow a more usual imperative approach.